# LiveData and Transformations.switchMap crashing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I've got an app where I want to add a status of some sort, and if added, I want my UI to show a snackbar saying it was added. I've got a repository, where I add my status. If successful, I'll post the value back to my ViewModel. Since it's a snackbar, I want to show it only once, so if I try to add a status again it won't reach the previous state it was in.

So I'm trying to implement the recommended approach from this article: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

So I've got the Event class added to my project.

Then my repository looks something like this:

```
private val _statusAdded = MutableLiveData<Event<AbstractRepositoryCallback.ResultState<Boolean>>>()
override val statusAdded: LiveData<Event<AbstractRepositoryCallback.ResultState<Boolean>>> = _statusAdded

val result = _firebaseFunctions.getHttpsCallable("someTable").call(data).awaitResult()

when(result)
{
is Result.Success -> this._statusAdded.postValue(Event(AbstractRepositoryCallback.ResultState(true, null)))
is Result.Error -> this._statusAdded.postValue(Event(AbstractRepositoryCallback.ResultState(false, MessageFactory.getError(R.string.create_status_failed_label))))
}
```

In my ViewModel, I listen to this LiveData like this:

```
val state: LiveData<DataHolder<Boolean>> = Transformations.switchMap(repository.statusAdded) { data ->
    getStatusAdded(data)
}

private fun getStatusAdded(data: Event<AbstractRepositoryCallback.ResultState<Boolean>>): LiveData<DataHolder<Boolean>> {
    data.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
        object : AbstractRepositoryCallback<Boolean>(it) {
            override fun onSuccess(data: Boolean) {
                liveData.value = DataHolder.success(data)
            }

            override fun onError(message: IMessage) {
                super.onError(message)
                liveData.value = DataHolder.error(message)
            }
        }
    }
    return liveData
}
```

The DataHolder class and AbstractRepositoryCallback are just some classes we've made to make stuff a bit more generic, so don't mind that.

Anyhow, when I try to add the status here, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldk/../../ViewModel$getStatusAdded$1$1;
    at ../../ViewModel.access$getStatusAdded(ViewModel.kt:53)
```

Hopefully someome can help me out with what's happening here, I'm new to this LiveData, but I've followed some guides on how to use it, and most people say this Event class is good for Snackbars etc, it just seems most examples are from ViewModel to Fragment/Activity, and not a bit before.

I open up a new ViewModel each time, so it gets destroyed, so I can't keep the getContentIfNotHandled stuff from the ViewModel. Because it'll always just be false.